# Converting a simple type xsd to a complex type to make wsd2apex work

Tags: wsdl2apex, wsdl

I have a simple type xsd element which i want to convert to a complex type because i want the final wsdl to be document type literal format. Could you guys help?

```
<xsd:element name="Service">
<xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:enumeration value="loan.CreateLead" />
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

I want this to be converted to a complex type with the same name element and having an enumeration value. Please let me know on this? The reason is salesforce wsdl parser is rejecting simple types and would only want complex types and  i need the complex type to be named Service which would accept the enumeration value?
 Thanks Buyan

Answer (score 3):

As per the documentation [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm), only the basic XML Schema data types are supported, nor are enum data types (not quite sure why tbh). So the simplest thing to do is to revert to the xsd:string data.

You have the following in your XML Schema.

```
<xsd:simpleType  name="ServiceType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="loan.CreateLead" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:element name="Service">
    <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="Service" type="h:ServiceType"  />
         </xsd:sequence>    
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

The child Service element inside the annoymous complex type has the type of h:ServiceType. This data type convention (extending the xsd:string data type to constrain it) is not supported. You need to simplify your XML Schema like so. This will not change the shape of the XML it describes, nor loose anything in the Apex generated since enum's are not supported anyway, so your not loosing anything, at least in Apex.

```
<xsd:element name="Service">
    <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="Service" type="xsd:string"  />
         </xsd:sequence>    
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried this but it gives me a parsing error because i think salesforce expects a complex type. Do you know how to convert this to a complex type with the same element name?

Comment: Thats strange as the original schema is an extension of a simple type to constrain it with an enum. Can you post a bit more of the WSDL in your question and perhaps link to to Gist of the fully WSDL?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3g0ogHiFUVNX0dNblJ4blBaT1E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have posted the wsdl on my google drive.

Comment: Ok I see now, your question looked like the xsd:element was a parent to the xsd:simpleType (which is a permitted convention in XML schema). I can see now from your WSDL this is not the case. I'll update my answer.